# Adding citations after manually writing the bibliography

Tags: errors, citing, overleaf

I am using Overleaf and I manually added the references, they are part of `main.tex`, right before the end of the document:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{paper}
Muster Mustermann (2019) \emph{Title 1}, University College.

\bibitem{article}
Author Authorin (2018) \emph{Title 2}, American Journal.
\end{thebibliography}
```

However, when I use \cite{paper} or \ref{article} within the text, the warning message "Citation/Reference XXX on page XXX undefined on input line XXX" appears.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about your document setup. E.g., which document class do you employ? Do you load any citation management packages, such as `cite`, `natbib`, or `apacite`? Incidentally, `\ref{article}` cannot be right; it should be `\cite{article}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `\cite` to do the citations, not `\ref`. The reason you're seeing a citation undefined message is that `\cite` gets its information about a reference from the previous run of LaTeX, so you'll need to run LaTeX twice to get the citation resolved. On the first run, you'll see something like the following in your log output:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `paper' on page 1 undefined on input line 5.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./x.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

but when you re-run, the citation will be available to LaTeX and you'll be able to  see your citation resolved.

Here's a complete example of the LaTeX showing your bibliography and a citation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{paper}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{paper}
Muster Mustermann (2019) \emph{Title 1}, University College.

\bibitem{article}
Author Authorin (2018) \emph{Title 2}, American Journal.
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```